# unnest list columns containing sf objects

Tags: r, tidyr, r-sf

I'm trying to `tidyr::unnest` a data frame list column containing `sf` objects.

For example, following this blog: http://r.iresmi.net/2019/03/27/open-and-merge-multiple-shapefiles/

Download shapefiles

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(fs)
library(httr)
library(leaflet)
# https://fr.actualitix.com/blog/shapefiles-des-departements-de-france.html
url <-  c("https://fr.actualitix.com/blog/actgeoshap/73-savoie.zip",
          "https://fr.actualitix.com/blog/actgeoshap/74-haute-savoie.zip")
dep <- str_extract(url, "\\d{2}.*$")
list(url, dep) %>% 
  pwalk(~ GET(.x, write_disk(.y)))
walk(dep, unzip, junkpaths = TRUE, exdir = "shp")
```

Read shapefiles into common table and unnest.

```
res <- dir_ls("shp", glob = "*.shp") %>% 
  tibble(fname = .) %>%
  mutate(data = map(fname, read_sf)) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_set_crs(2154)
```

However, this gives error

```
Error: No common type for `..1$data$geometry` <sfc_POLYGON> and `..2$data$geometry` <sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>.
```

Can `tidyr::unnest` be used in this manner?

EDIT: Using `sf` v 0.8-0

EDIT: My goal is for all `sf` objects in the list column `data` to be expanded out so all their columns are present in the new `sf` data frame. ie

```
sf1 <- dir_ls("shp", glob = "*.shp") %>% 
  tibble(fname = .) %>%
  mutate(data = map(fname, read_sf)) %>% 
  pluck(2,1) 

sf2 <- dir_ls("shp", glob = "*.shp") %>% 
  tibble(fname = .) %>%
  mutate(data = map(fname, read_sf)) %>% 
  pluck(2,2)

rbind(sf1, sf2)
```

Comment: What's your goal, to bind all the shapes into one `sf` object?

Comment: @camille edited post to clarify

Comment: Do you really need to read this into a complex structure at first or is the real question "How do I read a number of shapefiles and merge them into one spatial object?"? And your code works for me, expect for some warnings.

Comment: Should be working again with sf version 0.8-1 2020-01-28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems it’s a new bug after a new version (1.0) of `tidyr` (probably because of the `vctrs` package).
See [sf issues #1172](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1172#issuecomment-540552559)

Meanwhile you can use :

```
dir_ls("shp", glob = "*.shp") %>% 
  map(read_sf) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

(if the daframes structures are identical)

**Should be working again with sf version 0.8-1 2020-01-28**

Comment: I still have this problem with sf version 0.9-1, it misses the 'sf' class after unnest().

Comment: That was already the case before ; just add `st_as_sf()` after `unnest()`